# Setting page size for S3 Java API

Tags: java, amazon-s3

the S3 Java API default page size is 1000 objects per request.
Since I have tens of thousands of objects in my bucket I want to be able to list the objects in larger pages.

This is the code I use currently :

```
@Override
public S3SyncResult call() throws Exception {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    createRequest();
    ObjectListing listing = s3API.listS3Objects(createRequest());
    while (listing.isTruncated()) {
        log.debug("Received [" + listing.getObjectSummaries().size() + "] objects");
        listing = s3API.listS3Objects(listing);
    }
    log.debug("Listing took [" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "]");
    return null;
}

private ListObjectsRequest createRequest() {
    return new ListObjectsRequest(params.getBucket(),params.getPrefix(),null,null,2000);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: That it returns objects in a batch of 1000, where I'd like to be able to get 2000 or more per call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't, because this is a limitation in the underlying API.  The max you can fetch in a single request is 1,000.

> **GET Bucket (List Objects)**
>
> This implementation of the `GET` operation returns some or all (up to 1000) of the objects in a bucket.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) has this same limitation